# How to edit and update the data in sqlite database?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm new to android can any one give some examples of how to edit and update the data in sqlite database and retrieve it?

thanks in advance

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) If you're new to android, you should be looking at tutorials rather than SO

Comment: Please search before asking. there are lots of tutorial on Web.

Comment: You should Google such questions before asking here https://www.google.co.in/search?q=android+sqlite+database+example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the android beginner series by Travis(thenewboston) on youtube. He explains very  properly with development.
It is for absolute beginners so you wont be scared by anything. 
Here's the link - [Link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SUOWNXGRc6g&list=PL33384E9848C4F55E)

It starts from tutorial number 111.

Answer (score 3):

DataBaseHelper.class

```
 private static String DB_PATH;

public static final String DB_NAME = "product";
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
      super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
      DB_PATH = context.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath();
      openDataBase();
      getWritableDatabase();
 }

 public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
     String myPath = DB_PATH + "/" + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
}

     public void insertProducts(String name,Double price) {
        try {
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put("Name", name);
            values.put("Price",price);
            myDataBase.insert(DB_NAME , null, values);
            myDataBase.setTransactionSuccessful();          
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error in transaction", "Error", e);
        } finally {
            myDataBase.endTransaction();
        }
        }
```

Activity.java

```
  DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(WaiterActivity.this);
  db.insertProducts("Desktop",5000.00)
```